# NAS file transfer works in 12.04 buy aborts in 14.04

Tags: nas

Files readable and transferrable with 12.04 cannot be copied by fresh install of 14.04 . Directories and files are visible and they can be opened by some programs eg .stl files will open with netfab basic but I cannot copy or move them. Error is 'Software caused connection abort'

Comment: What's the format of the NAS partition? Are we to assume NTFS?